Efficiency of various Panel Data Models
I'm preparing for an Econometrics exam, and am confused about what makes a Panel Data Model efficient. For Pooled OLS, why do we require heteroskedasticity & E^2a=0 for the model to be efficient?
I understand efficiency is when the model has the lowest possible variance, but don't understand how this relates to the various requirements my lecturer has set out.
Any help would be much appreciated.


Hi: My guess is that the box is not clear to most which is why you're not getting responses. For example, when you write $v_{it} = \alpha_{i} + u_{it}$ what is the meaning of the subscripts ?".
